# Bill a customer in paypal from a service hosted in azure cloud

Tags: c#, azure, paypal

I build a WCF service that fetches credit card details and makes a charge. My WCF service is hosted in azure cloud. When I create a request for Paypal, I use [this solution](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Online-payment-using-Paypal-API-2134.php).

There you can see the type DoDirectPaymentRequestDetailsType that I need to fill. One of the parameters is:

```
dPRequestDetailsType.IPAddress = "192.168.10.182"; //get the ipaddress of the machine and Set IP
```

What is the value that I need to put there?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Azure Portal and view the Dashboard for the Cloud Service in question.  On the right side, look for **PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS**.  Note that this VIP changes when/if you update new code to the STAGING slot and then swap the VIP from STAGING to PRODUCTION.